# Info hidden in list item

Tags: java, listview, primefaces

I would like to have some info saved in a list item other than what I have to show on the item itself. Is there any way I can save a `string` or `integer` in a listview item without it being a `textview` or `label`?

Comment: Please be more clear in your question, provide more informations

Comment: for instance I have a movie database. movie table has ID, name, genre and description. the list item will show name genre and description but i dont want to show the ID. I will be needing the ID so that I can edit or delete the info via sqlite. is there i way i can save the ID of the movie in the list item?

Comment: Yes you can choose to not show the id and make it as a `Rowkey` of your table (I suppose that you want to show your listView in a datatable) when you select one or more than one movie (make an update or simply delete it ) it will work with the `Rowkey` to identifie the data that you want to delete (or update) look at this example : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml hope that help

Comment: there are two ways to acheive this, 1)set visibility = gone for the views that you don't want to show in list item. (or) use this 2) create your own data model with getter and setter methods to access your data, it will hide the data that you don't show in list item.